# How to calculate percentage and show in third textbox?

Tags: jquery

In `mypercenttextbox` I need to put whatever percent value when
 `(myfirstnumber/ 100)  mysecondnumber;`

```html
myfirstnumber
<input type="number" value="F" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"/>

mysecondnumber
<input type="number" value="S" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"/>

<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox ">
```

I am trying to do this with jQuery :

```
function ShowPercentage() {
    var FirstNumID = $("[id$=" + "myfirstnumber").attr("id");
    var FirstNumVal = $("#" + myfirstnumber).val();

    var SecondNumID = $("[id$=" + "mysecondnumber").attr("id");
    var SecondNumVal = $("#" + mysecondnumber).val();

    var percentVal = (myfirstnumber - mysecondnumber) * (100 / mysecondnumber);

    $("[id$=" + "mypercenttextbox ").val(percentVal);
}
```

In the code here-above, I am able to get percentage in, but I'm getting it as eg. `9.09090909090909` whereas I want to show like `10%`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Please take the time to format your questions so they're at least somewhat readable. It makes it easier and quicker for people to read and help you.

Comment: try `$("[id$=" + "mypercenttextbox ").val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%');` or with `$("[id$=" + "mypercenttextbox ").val(Math.ceil(parseInt(percentVal)) + '%');`. The second code rounds a number upward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adjust on your example code "9.09090909090909"

**As downward**

```
$("[id$=" + "mypercenttextbox ").val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%');
// output 9%
```

**As upward**

```
$("[id$=" + "mypercenttextbox ").val(Math.ceil(parseInt(percentVal)) + '%');
// output 10%
```

**As Decimal**

```
$("[id$=" + "mypercenttextbox ").val(percentVal.toFixed(2) + '%')
// output 9.09%
```

**I updated your Fiddle to a recommand (for me!) version:**

```js
function ShowPercentage() {
  
    var $inputs = $('input');
  
    // get values
    var firstNumVal = $inputs.eq(0).val();
    var SecondNumVal = $inputs.eq(1).val();

    // compute something
    var percentVal = (firstNumVal - SecondNumVal) * (100 / SecondNumVal);

    // set value
    $inputs.eq(2).val(parseInt(percentVal) + '%');
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#computeSomething').on('click', ShowPercentage);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
myfirstnumber
<input type="number" value="F" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"> <br>
mysecondnumber
<input type="number" value="S" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"> <br>
Result
<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox "><br>
<button id="computeSomething">Compute someThing!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fully working demo of how to achieve what you're going for :

```js
function ShowPercentage() {
    var FirstNumVal = 0 + Number($("#myfirstnumber").val());
    var SecondNumVal = 0 + Number($("#mysecondnumber").val());
    $("#mypercenttextbox").val(Math.round(FirstNumVal/(SecondNumVal) * 100) / 100 + '%');
}

ShowPercentage();
$('input[type=number]').on('keyup', ShowPercentage);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="1" class="1" id="myfirstnumber"/>

<input type="number" value="100" class="1" id="mysecondnumber"/>

<input type="percentage" value="P" class="1" id="mypercenttextbox" readonly>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/pj8rdeep/4/))

Comment: Also nice version! Btw: you forget that he like a result `like 10%`. You missed ceil and the percentage sign.

Comment: @kaito : Just fixed that!

Comment: cool :) .on('keyup change', ShowPercentage); and its perfect that the question creator can learn :)

Comment: you guys are awesome. Thank you